# Making a face from 3 selected vertices

Tags: modeling

I am trying to work on modeling a spoon for a basic project, but I am stuck on making the "stick" handle. I am trying to merge three vertices into a face, but I don't understand what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include reference images of the problem topology?

Comment: Select the 3 verts and press F for "fill"